# Location update Background task been terminated after 3 minutes, if no permission is granted. how can we extend that?

Tags: swift, core-location, ios10, background-process

I am trying to Fetch user location at Predefined Time Interval (i.e. 30 Minutes), I have enabled location update in background modes, For testing purpose I am creating local notification every time when location is been detected.if internet is available and location permission is granted then everything works fine but if no location permission then after 3 minutes app is been terminated in background.

I have Used Following approach, please do let me know if I have missed anything ?

1)I have also created background task and invalidate background task at every 150 Seconds or less seconds. In Restart Method Location manager is

```
func beginNewBackgroundTask()
    {

        var previousTaskId = currentBgTaskId;
        currentBgTaskId = UIApplication.shared.beginBackgroundTask(expirationHandler:
            {

        })
        if let taskId = previousTaskId{
            UIApplication.shared.endBackgroundTask(taskId)
            previousTaskId = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid

        }
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: BackgroundLocationManager.BACKGROUND_TIMER, target: self, selector: #selector(self.restart),userInfo: nil, repeats: false)

    }
```

2)In Restart Method I am calling update location method, if permission is already been granted.and if Permission is not granted then I will call initiate background task method again to keep app running, and send user notification.

```
func restart ()
{

        if(CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == CLAuthorizationStatus.restricted ||           CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == CLAuthorizationStatus.denied )
        {
            self. beginNewBackgroundTask()
            self.scheduleNotification(Message:”Please enable Location”)
        }
        else
        {
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        }
}
```

If app has no permission of location then new background task is not being created and app will be terminated in background after 3 minutes.

Can we keep app running in background if there is no permission for location ?

Strange Thing if app is in **debug mode** (Attached with mac) then  notification is been generated for 8 - 9 Minutes, but without debug mode only3 Minutes  did I miss something ? Or we can not keep app running in background more then 3 minutes if there is no permission for location

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood, but wouldn't it be very rude to allow this in case the user did not grand permission?

Comment: Yes, Actually You misunderstood, If user didn't grant permission then we need to show him local notification saying that "please enable your location", App is intended to track sales people for an organization that's why all time location is necessary.

Thanks